# Can you delegate administration of an OU to a group or role within the OU?

Tags: active-directory

Can the group with delegated administration of an OU reside in the OU such that the group has the ability to manage it's own memberships?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the delegate can be a member of the group to which they are delegated permissions.